# SQL Server compare charaters and update column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two columns in a table.

```
     x    |    y
  ========|=========
    AMDN  | AMDNOXYZ
    AMDNO | AMNOXYZ
```

I want to compare the two columns and update column `y` based on certain conditions on column `x`. If there are characters in column `y` which are not present in column x then just delete those characters not the whole string. The idea is to compare character by character in both columns. At any point in time there cannot be any character in column `y` which is not present in column `x` or in other words column `y` can only be a subset of column `x`.

So the result will be

```
     x    |    y
  ========|=========
    AMDN  | AMDN
    AMDNO | AMNO
```

Please help.

Comment: Post your query attempt. We are not here to do your work.

Comment: @stefan I have no idea about what function to use. I found no way to convert a varchar to char array for comparison. I'm am really asking for help. Atleast guide upon what to use.

Comment: The way you stated your question only people who does your entire work can supply a correct answer. If you want to ask a more generic question of your sub-question it would probably give you a lot more votes. Most of us are professionals and we dont do other programmers work for free.

Comment: Usually I don't process data on the db layer, rather on the business layer. In particular strings camparison and manipulation is very boring with sql-server functions. Can you approach the problem on the business layer?

Comment: @ADC No this has to be updated in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function created in sql server which takes x and y columns as input and returns the desired output

```
create function remove_char(@x_string varchar(500),@y_string varchar(500))
returns varchar(500)
as
begin
    declare @Y  table(autoid int identity,c char(1))
    declare @i int=1;declare @c char(1);
    while(LEN(@y_string)>=@i)
    begin
        select @c=substring(@y_string,@i,1);
        Insert into @Y values(@c)
        select @i=@i+1
    end

    declare @X table(autoid int identity,c char(1))
    set @i=1;
    while(LEN(@x_string)>=@i)
    begin
        select @c=substring(@x_string,@i,1);
        Insert into @X values(@c)
        select @i=@i+1
    end
return( select STUFF(( select ''+c from @Y
 where c in (select c from @X) order by autoid
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') )
end
```

example

`select dbo.remove_char('AMDNO','AMNOXYZ')`

you can use this function to update your table

```
 update <table> set y=dbo.remove_char(x,y)
```